# What does the sign language near the ending mean?

Tags: koe-no-katachi, sign-language

Close to the ending of *Koe no Katachi*, Nishimiya Shouko did a motion with one of her hands below the other and her pinkies intertwined. What does this mean?

[image: the sign language]

Comment: As in sign language, a screenshot would help your quest for an answer.

Comment: From the intertwined pinkies, looks like ["promise"](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11164532121), though the overall shape looks different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before the sign in your picture, which stands for *promise* (約束) also known as 'pinky promise', Shouko puts two hands together. Which stands for *friends* (友達).

Which would come down to: "friends promise" 
And can be inteprated as "Promise to be friends forever"